# Displaying seperate images on top of background while hovering over grid

Tags: html, css

first question here:

I'm a little bit struggling with css (not that much experience).

So basically I got an background image which is a map (google maps screenshot).
It's a .jpg and has a size of 1623px x 765px (yeah weird pixel measures).

What I did then is creating a grid with four rectangles. The grids background is the map-image.

What I wanna do now is that when I hover over each of these grid-rectangles, an individual transparent .png (which has the same size as the map-image which has also some elements in it like a path for each rectangle respectively) should display with some smooth transition into opacity = 1.

My problem is that whatever I try in the end I end up having the .pngs only displayed in their respective grid-rectangle.

So I'm not really sure how to "overlap" the grids and make them visible to the full screen.
And also I don't really know how I can place all "hidden" .pngs on top of each other and on top of the background image.

This Code was my starting point. From there on I had several approaches with e.g. a html map.
But map was not good because the pixels are fixed size.

There was another approach with having 4 different bg-classes (bg1,..,bg4) and then I wanted to do this:

```
.bg1 {
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/route_1.png);
}

...

#route-area1:hover .bg1 {
    opacity = 1;
}

...
```

But the background got never displayed. z-index didn't help either.

So now I just reverted all back to this starting point because things got messy.

CSS

```
.route-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    background: url('../images/route_map.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.route-container > div {
    height: 382px;
}

.route-area {
    display: block;
    height: 765px;
    opacity: 0;

}

#route-area1 {
    background-color: tomato;
    background-image: url(../images/route_1.png);
}

#route-area2 {
    background-color: royalblue;
    background-image: url(../images/route_2.png);
}

#route-area3 {
    background-color: gold;
    background-image: url(../images/route_3.png);
}

#route-area4 {
    background-color: silver;
    background-image: url(../images/route_4.png);
}

#route-area1:hover,
#route-area2:hover,
#route-area3:hover,
#route-area4:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="route-container">
    <div id="route-area1" class="route-area">Child 1</div>
    <div id="route-area2" class="route-area">Child 2</div>
    <div id="route-area3" class="route-area">Child 3</div>
    <div id="route-area4" class="route-area">Child 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: THe background-image is supposed to be in the background of the element, so it won't exceed the size of it. You should try something different. You'll probably need a JS. From the top of my head I think it would be nice to have an html attribute (like data-background) with the image to load when assing the mouse on the square and make JS change the loading image and setting the class to "load", in the class you set animation and opacity to 1 and get a nice transition.

Comment: @teefars yeah I tried to remove the background-image from the #route-area so it would be only a pseudo grid element for hovering.

Then I tried to add 4 new classes with the background-images like in the little code segement in the text.

Do you think this is possible without javascript?

Comment: Well yes, it would require a little broken semantic but it is doable. You'll probably need to try the `:target` pseudo selector or the `:checked`. Both would require a click (or a js firing a click). Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target), [this](https://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/QwvxOp)

Comment: Or, for even more advanced shananigans, for just a hover you could work with selectors. Sounds simpler actually. I'll create a sample so you can visualize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, the background-image will fit only the bounds of the element it is meant to be a background of.

In your case the best option would be having the background changed in other ways, I can think of several ways to do so:

1. Add a pseudo element after the div, with position absolute or fixed behind everything. You could find some z-index issues but it is doable. (CSS only)
2. You could create a div at the end of the parent holding the background to be changed (css only)
3. If you need to click, you could work with the :target pseudo selector
4. Change the background with JS

The easier should be **2**. You could even have 1  for each image, there are some advantages: if you use a  tag it will download the image before trying to show, so when fadin in it will be instantly. But that would mean more load time for your entire page. If you let as background-image, it will load when required, which could take a couple of notable miliseconds (check the example above)

```css
.route-container {
    display: grid;/* ? */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* ? */
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);  /* ? */
    grid-gap: 5px;  /* ? */
    background: url('https://desenio.pt/bilder/artiklar/zoom/8450_2.jpg?imgwidth=435&qt=');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 400px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
}

.route-area {
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition:all .2s ease;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

#route-area1 {
    background-color: tomato;
    background-image: url(../images/route_1.png);
}

#route-area2 {
    background-color: royalblue;
    background-image: url(../images/route_2.png);
}

#route-area3 {
    background-color: gold;
    background-image: url(../images/route_3.png);
}

#route-area4 {
    background-color: silver;
    background-image: url(../images/route_4.png);
}

#route-area1:hover,
#route-area2:hover,
#route-area3:hover,
#route-area4:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#bgimage{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:silver;
   opacity:0;
   transition:all .5s ease;
   z-index:1;
   background-position:center;
   background-size:cover;
}

.route-area:hover ~ #bgimage{
  opacity:1;
}

#route-area1:hover ~ #bgimage{
   background-image:url('https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF-1200-80.jpg');
}
#route-area2:hover ~ #bgimage{
   background-image:url('https://static.independent.co.uk/2021/06/16/08/newFile-4.jpg?width=982&height=726&auto=webp&quality=75');
}
#route-area3:hover ~ #bgimage{
   background-image:url('https://i.natgeofe.com/n/3861de2a-04e6-45fd-aec8-02e7809f9d4e/02-cat-training-NationalGeographic_1484324.jpg');
}
#route-area4:hover ~ #bgimage{
   background-image:url('https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/06/Layer-1704-1200x630.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="route-container">
    <div id="route-area1" class="route-area">Child 1</div>
    <div id="route-area2" class="route-area">Child 2</div>
    <div id="route-area3" class="route-area">Child 3</div>
    <div id="route-area4" class="route-area">Child 4</div>
    <div id="bgimage"></div>
</div>
```